# Updating label text from the value from datagrid view cell C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, label

I have a Data grid view where i enter the time hrs  and beneath it is a label in footer at the end of each column of dataGridview column which calculates the daywise total hours for each day for an activity like
   |Mon| Tue| Wed

|1            |  2               |  3

|2            |  3               |  4

tot 3       5        6

For normal entry it is working fine but if i am doing any change in (say) first row Monday time from 1 i am changing it to 5 then only that rows total is coming

in this case total is coming to be 5 2 3

That is next row is not considering in calculating in total

Kindly let me know where i am wrong.

```
 public void calcdaywisetotal()
    {
        try
        {
            if (dgvTimeReport.RowCount > 1)
            {
                decimal montot = 0, tuetot = 0, wedtot = 0, thutot = 0, fritot = 0, sattot = 0, suntot = 0, tottot = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    //decimal MonTotal = decimal.Parse(lblMonTotal.Text);
                    montot = montot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Monday"].Value);
                    lblMonTotal.Text = montot.ToString();
                    //monday
                    if (lblMonTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strmontot = new string[2];

                        if (lblMonTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strmontot = lblMonTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblMonTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strmontot = lblMonTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strmontot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strmontot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblMonTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblMonTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblMonTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblMonTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        montot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblMonTotal.Text);
                    }

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    tuetot = tuetot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Tuesday"].Value);
                    lblTueTotal.Text = tuetot.ToString();
                    //tuesday
                    if (lblTueTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strtuetot = new string[2];

                        if (lblTueTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strtuetot = lblTueTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblTueTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strtuetot = lblTueTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strtuetot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strtuetot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblTueTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblTueTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblTueTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblTueTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        tuetot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblTueTotal.Text);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    wedtot = wedtot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Wednesday"].Value);
                    lblWedTotal.Text = wedtot.ToString();
                    //Wednesday

                    if (lblWedTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strwedtot = new string[2];

                        if (lblWedTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strwedtot = lblWedTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblWedTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strwedtot = lblWedTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strwedtot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strwedtot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblWedTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblWedTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblWedTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblWedTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        wedtot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblWedTotal.Text);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    thutot = thutot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Thursday"].Value);
                    lblThuTotal.Text = thutot.ToString();
                    //Thursday
                    if (lblThuTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strthutot = new string[2];

                        if (lblThuTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strthutot = lblThuTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblThuTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strthutot = lblThuTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strthutot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strthutot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblThuTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblThuTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblThuTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblThuTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        thutot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblThuTotal.Text);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {

                    fritot = fritot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Friday"].Value);
                    lblFriTotal.Text = fritot.ToString();
                    //Friday
                    if (lblFriTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strfritot = new string[2];

                        if (lblFriTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strfritot = lblFriTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblFriTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strfritot = lblFriTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strfritot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strfritot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblFriTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblFriTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblFriTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblFriTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        fritot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblFriTotal.Text);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    sattot = sattot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Saturday"].Value);
                    lblSatTotal.Text = sattot.ToString();
                    //Saturday
                    if (lblSatTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strsattot = new string[2];

                        if (lblSatTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strsattot = lblSatTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblSatTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strsattot = lblSatTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strsattot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strsattot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblSatTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblSatTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblSatTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblSatTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        sattot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblSatTotal.Text);
                    }

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    suntot = suntot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Sunday"].Value);
                    lblSunTotal.Text = suntot.ToString();
                    //Sunday

                    if (lblSunTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strsuntot = new string[2];

                        if (lblSunTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strsuntot = lblSunTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblSunTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strsuntot = lblSunTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strsuntot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strsuntot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblSunTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblSunTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblSunTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblSunTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        suntot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblSunTotal.Text);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTimeReport.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    tottot = tottot + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvTimeReport.Rows[i].Cells["Total1"].Value);
                    lblTotTotal.Text = tottot.ToString();
                    //Total
                    if (lblTotTotal.Text != null)
                    {
                        string[] strtottot = new string[2];

                        if (lblTotTotal.Text.Contains(","))
                        {
                            strtottot = lblTotTotal.Text.Split(',');
                        }

                        if (lblTotTotal.Text.Contains("."))
                        {
                            strtottot = lblTotTotal.Text.Split('.');
                        }

                        int hr = Convert.ToInt32(strtottot[0]);
                        int min = Convert.ToInt32(strtottot[1]);

                        if (min < 60)
                        {
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblTotTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblTotTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hr = hr + 1;
                            min = min - 60;
                            if (min >= 10)
                            {
                                lblTotTotal.Text = hr + "." + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblTotTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    tottot = Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotTotal.Text);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                lblMonTotal.Text = "0.00";
                lblTueTotal.Text = "0.00";
                lblWedTotal.Text = "0.00";
                lblThuTotal.Text = "0.00";
                lblFriTotal.Text = "0.00";
                lblSatTotal.Text = "0.00";
                lblSunTotal.Text = "0.00";
                lblTotTotal.Text = "0.00";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Excp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Excp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            log.Fatal("Exception -" + Excp.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the part of your if section, when don't enter, the "montot" clear he's value,
add else:

```
    if (lblMonTotal.Text.Contains(","))
    {
        strmontot = lblMonTotal.Text.Split(',');
    }
    if (lblMonTotal.Text.Contains("."))
    {
        strmontot = lblMonTotal.Text.Split('.');
    }
    else
    {
        strmontot = new string[2] { montot.ToString(), "0" };
    }


    else if (hr != 0)
    {
        lblMonTotal.Text = hr + ".0" + min;
    }
```

Edit: them change the "else" for "else if":

Comment: we dont require else there since for entering in hrs only these 2 formats are required either 9.00 or 9,00 both representing 9 hrs. Also  to check for values we have if (lblMonTotal.Text != null) condition if one has left it as 0 or blank  it's else part is there to be  else
            {
                lblMonTotal.Text = "0.00";} This is only formatiing error but the actual problem is i want the total value to update if user update some other previous value. Thanks